# Need to detect which <script> block interact with which other <script> block in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, scope, global-object

I need to check whether javascript in one  block, can access or manipulate javascript in any another script block in a webpage. For Example, the second  block (inside div) access the first script block inside body.

```
<body>
<script>
    var first_script_block=0;
</script>
<div>
<script >
    var secondblock_acess_first =first_script_block; 
</script>
</div>
</body>
```

I though it a lot.  I feel horrible. I need some ideas. :(

Comment: Why do you feel horrible? what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

All the scripts share the same `global-object`

If you don't want it to happen(it's hard to tell from your question) use closures:

```
<script>
(function (){
    // here is the code for the first script tag.
})();
</script>
...
<script>
(function (){
    // here is the code for the second script tag
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MQXHQ/). See, you can create a variable in one and modify it in the other. It doesn't really matter how your JS is split up in script blocks.

Output:

```
In first block
0
In second block
1
```